# .net core, NUnit, HttpClinet: How to expect Forbidden error?

Tags: .net, nunit, httpclient

I'm implementing integration tests with .net core and NUnit.
Here's the controller:

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Guid guid)
    { 
      if(<condition>)
      {
        return Forbid("Message");
      }
    }
}
```

Here's the test:

```
[Test]
public async Task Test_Forbidden()
{

    var httpResponse = await _client.GetAsync(<url>);
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, httpResponse.StatusCode, "Status code is invalid");
}
```

The thing is: 
if I'm expecting StatusCodes like **Ok**, **NotFound**, or **BadRequests** everything goes well.
But if I'm expecting ***Forbidden***, then the execution of the GetAsync() method is interrupted with *InvalidOperationException*.
Have anybody an idea, how to prevent throwing an exception and to make the GetAsync() method return a response with the appropriate status code?
I may catch an exception in the test and check the message, but this approach doesn't seem to be very clean.

Comment: Based on the exception you indicated is happening I believe this is  an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). According to documentation `InvalidOperationException` is thrown by [`GetAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=net-5.0) because `The requestUri must be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.`

Comment: @Nkosi  thanks, you were right. Anyway, I've found the solution (see answer below).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple. I had to return not just a **Forbid(Message)**, but

```
return StatusCode((int) HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "The conference is locked");
```